# Нет перевода в предупреждении в очереди на закрытие

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок

Заметил что нет перевода на проверке бдительности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже добавил перевод:

[Этот вопрос не нужно удалять. Удаление должно быть применено для сообщений, которые не имеют никакой ценности. Этот вопрос предлагает полезную информацию и может быть отредактирован для исправления мелких проблем. При просмотре таких сообщений нажмите **Оставить открытым**.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16009)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Внёс некоторые изменения](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16009) в предложенный вариант. Стоит обратить внимание на следующие термины:

- post - это "сообщение"
- Looks Good - это "Выглядит нормально"

Будет на сайте в новых сборках (вероятно, уже в январе). Текущая rev 2021.12.22.41046

Comment: я понял, спасибо) буду знать :D